# LuaLaTeX: How to reduce the file size of the generated PDF on the fly?

Tags: graphics, luatex, external-files, size, memory

I'm using LaTeX to generate a PDF that will have around 1500 - 2000 pages. The PDF includes a lot of pictures. Approximately 5000 photographs (JPG) that are each 2MB and a couple of hundred smaller icons (JPG) that are around 500Kb.

Generating the first 400 pages results in a PDF with a size of 1.76GB. Generating more pages is not possible at the moment, since my laptop is running out of memory. What I want to achieve is to reduce the size of the generated PDF without touching the original images. Are there any options to set that I could use the reduce the size of the PDF?

I found a lot of similar questions, but all of them are taking about reducing the file size after the PDF has been generated. I need to do it on the fly.

Comment: JPEG images are represented in PDF in the same format as in separate files. No matter what you do to the remaining document, every PDF containing 10GB of unchanged JPEG images will be at least 10GB big. So any approach has to involve changing the source images.

Comment: If I can't change these original files for some reasons, isn't there an option to do that on the fly while they are included into the PDF?

Comment: why don't you create smaller copies in some other folder?

Comment: I see @UlrikeFischer suggestion as to the most reasonable one. If you know more or less the size at which they are included, you can scale them to say, 150dpi (creating `image-150.jpg` from `image.jpg` for example and include that. The size-reduction scripts you run on the PDF will do a very similar thing.

Comment: I think resizing images one the fly should be possible, but then compiling this document could take *days*!  More so, it will take days *each time your compile*!

Comment: Better not @HenriMenke :) It already takes minutes...

Comment: but you didn't answer the question why you don't resize the images in advance, which is likely to be quicker and simpler (but take a bit of disk space)

Comment: I can't change the original images. But yes, I just didn't thought about copying all of them and reduce the sizes of the copies. So that's definitively the way to go I think. However, I then have to figure out a script to do that preserving the folder structure. I don't want to do that manually for over 5000 pictures in 1000 folders.